# You can not apply multiple bindings to same element

Tags: knockout.js

I am using **knockoutjs** with **MVC5** to show the list of employee according role of employee. According to role list of employee should be changed. For the first time when I select the role everything is working fine but when I change the role then getting an

Error

> "You can not apply multiple bindings to same element."

I tried to get the reason behind this and solution, then got one solution that we need to use ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("abc")); but it is not working.

Code

```
var initialData = [{
  availableItems: data.availableItems
}, {
  selectedItems: data.selectedItems
}];

function Item(titleText, userId, isSelected) {
  this.title = ko.observable(titleText);
  this.isSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
  this.userId = ko.observable(userId);
}

var SelectableItemViewModel = function(items) {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable("");
  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[0].availableItems, function(item) {
    return new Item(item.UserName, item.UserId, item.Status);
  }));

  self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[1].selectedItems, function(item) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableItems(), function(itm) {
      return item.UserName == itm.title();
    });

  }));


  self.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
    debugger;
    var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
    if (!filter) {
      return this.availableItems();
    } else {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.availableItems(), function(item) {

        return item.title().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1;
      });
    }
    alert(this.availableItems());
  }, self);

  // Operations

  self.removeItem = function(removedItem) {
    self.selectedItems.remove(removedItem);
  };
}

var vm = new SelectableItemViewModel(initialData);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetAllUsersByRoleInUtility", "Home")",
                    data: { utilityId: currentUtilityId, roleId: currentRoleId },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        initialData[0].availableItems = data.availableItems;
                        initialData[1].selectedItems = data.selectedItems;
                        vm = new SelectableItemViewModel(initialData)

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('Oops! something went wrong.');
                    }
                });
```

I am using **knockoutjs** for the first time,

please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Show us your code. You're probably calling `ko.applyBindings` multiple times, whereas you should use `ko.observable` and `observableArray`s to swap out data.

Comment: @user3297291 , I added code in question.I'm doing all this on success of ajax call.

Comment: Add the success callback of your ajax call as well. The code you've added doesn't apply bindings multiple times, but the lack of `updateItems` logic makes me think you're trying to re-apply bindings when the new data is loaded...

Comment: please add the html as well

Comment: If I remove call to  ko.applyBindings(vm) on ajax success then it is not throwing an error but it is not binding data to element :-( .

Answer (score 0):

When you're loading data via ajax, you'll need to decide how you want to update the code behind your UI. An important decision:

1. Create new viewmodels with the new data
2. Re-use the same viewmodels, update the data inside them, or

---

### Option 1

This is what you're trying to do, and you almost succeeded. When you want to create a new viewmodel in your success callback, you'll have to make sure it's wrapped in an observable.

A (simplified) example that relates to your situation:

```js
// Construct the initial, empty UI
ko.applyBindings(new App());


function App() {
  this.selectableListVM = ko.observable(new SelectableList([]));
  
  // Later (using ajax), swap out the vm
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.selectableListVM(new SelectableList([1,2,3]));
  }.bind(this), 3000);

};

function SelectableList(items) {
  this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: selectableListVM">
  <span data-bind="visible: !items().length">loading..</span>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Option 2

Option 2 is a bit harder to implement, but can be more efficient. You need to clearly define the borders between data, models and states. For example, available items might not change, while selections *do*. E.g.:

```js
// Construct the initial, empty UI

var SelectableList = function() {
  this.items = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  // This is automatically updated when you update items via ajax
  this.selectedItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.items().filter(function(item) {
      return item.selected;
    })
  }, this);
  
};

SelectableList.prototype.loadItems = function() {
  // timeout to mock ajax
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.items([
      { name: 1, selected: Math.random() > 0.5 },
      { name: 2, selected: Math.random() > 0.5 },
      { name: 3, selected: Math.random() > 0.5 },
    ]);
  }.bind(this), 200);
}
      
ko.applyBindings(new SelectableList());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: loadItems">Load new state</button>
```